maven-dependency-plugin reports unused dependencies only when run without clean
The checks pass when I run clean verify.
[INFO] --- dependency:3.8.1:analyze-only (analyze-only) @ server ---
[INFO] No dependency problems found

But they fail when I then run just verify.
dependency:3.8.1:analyze-only (analyze-only) @ server ---
[ERROR] Unused declared dependencies found:
[ERROR]    org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-verifier:jar:4.1.4:test
[ERROR]    com.toomuchcoding.jsonassert:jsonassert:jar:0.8.0:test
[ERROR]    com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[ERROR]    org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test

I'm not sure how an un-clean build would cause unused dependencies to appear.
Since those are all test dependencies the Spring Cloud Contract is the most likely culprit.
Maybe on repeated run it doesn't add a source directory to the build?

Adding this makes the build result stable - I get a pass on the dependency check in both cases.
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>target/generated-test-sources/contracts</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

I've reported this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/issues/2144
